# I need to upload templates through django admin panel which contain index file along with static files

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am trying to make a portal where I take landing page template from different users and check manually that template is working file or not.

If everything looks good then I want  to upload that theme from my django admin panel which create a new folder for every template like in this case its template1, `template/theme/template1/index.html` folder and also same with static files I want to upload zip file for all folders of static file and what will happen in backend is it go to folder `static/template1/(unzipped static files)` where unzipped static files is the location where all the static file will unzip itself so that my index.html and static files can communicate with each other.

I am not able to find any solution for this.

How can we make a model for uploading file like this to make a new folder every time?

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class themes(models.Model):
     index_file = models.filefield(upload_to=???????)
     static_files = models.filefield(upload_to =?????)
```

Also I don't want to do collect static every time i upload a new template design.

Edit 2 here >>
In my models.py I tried doing this but I am getting errors in it. , where I am doing wrong ?

```
def index_path_upload(instance, filename):
    if not instance.pk:
       # get count of all object, so is will be unique
       number = instance.__class__.objects.count() + 1
    else:
       number = instance.pk
    # replace filename to all object have the same
    filename = "index.html"
    return f"templates/theme/template{number}/{filename}"

def static_path_upload(instance, filename):
    if not instance.pk:
       # get count of all object, so is will be unique
       number = instance.__class__.objects.count() + 1
    else:
       number = instance.pk
    # replace filename to all object have the same
    return f"static/template{number}/+.zip"


class themes(models.Model):
     index_file = models.FileField(upload_to=index_path_upload)
     static_file = models.FileField(upload_to=static_path_upload)
```

do I need to add other things in my setings file , currently this is what I have.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')


MEDIA_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not like this ?

the `upload_to` key in FileField accept a function like this

```
def index_path_upload(instance, filename):
    if not instance.pk:
       # get count of all object, so is will be unique
       number = instance.__class__.objects.count() + 1
    else:
       number = instance.pk
    # replace filename to all object have the same
    filename = "index.html"
return f"template/theme/template{number}/{filename}"
```

the `instance` params is your object ( themes models )
,the `filename` params is original filename of uploaded files

so your models like

```
def index_path_upload(instance, filename):
  ...

class themes(models.Model):
     index_file = models.filefield(upload_to=index_path_upload)
     ...
```

***edit:***

```
from django.conf import settings
import os


def index_path_upload(instance, filename):
    if not instance.pk:
       # get count of all object, so is will be unique
       number = instance.__class__.objects.count() + 1
    else:
       number = instance.pk
    # replace filename to all object have the same
    filename = "index.html"
    path =  f"templates/theme/template{number}/{filename}"
    return os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, path)
```

is will uploaded on your root directory ( where is manage.py ) + path
be warning with that , is a big security flaw !

Comment: What is instance here , and what it is referring to? I don't understand it properly what are you trying to explain here , could you please elaborate more?

Comment: is changed ;), sorry for my very bad english :D

Comment: I understand that , I will check this and thank you a lot for being a helping hand.

Comment: rgermain I tried doing so but I am getting errors , I edited in my question what I was doing with your solution , could you please see it. and let me know what's wrong with what I did.

Comment: which errors you get ?  i see 2 error , in function "static_path_upload" , you extract the zip file with "ZipFile" after return , it's can be work , for extract zip you need to do that after django saved your file, the upload_to=funciton is n=only to generate the path, no more , so best solustion is on signals , but is not important now , the seconde in themes models you have the same name  filed "index_file"

Comment: I corrected the mentioned errors but I am getting this issues , I want to upload static file in static folder of my main directory while using this method the files are uploading in location static/static/template1/.zip and same with index file its uploading to static/templates/theme/template1/index.html , while what I want is to upload file in my main directory folders where static and templates are my main directory folders. while I want to upload static file on location static/template1/.zip and index file to templates/theme/template1/index.html see edit 2 in question.